# Does InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(); involve DNS-Server?

Tags: java, dns, ip, host

With the following code

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

it is possible to get the hosts address. But how does the JVM find that out?

The Java API only tells you that it returns it ([API Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29)), but is there a DNS-Server involved, and if yes, when is it called?

And if it is only called once how is the server name saved locally?

Comment: BTW, it is slightly dangerous to rely on that your host has only one address. Most systems have e.g. an automatically configured IPv6 stack with several addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual implementation is done with JNI, in native code, so it is going to differ from platform to platform.

That said, there is no reason one needs to do DNS to lookup an ip address on a machine where the network cards are located.  One can just read the ip information from the network cards.

The bad news:  There is no way of knowing for certain if this will do a DNS lookup on any platform that Java runs upon, as it is native code, and the possibility of a machine doing a DNS lookup even when it is not actually necessary exists.

The good news:  On my linux box, it doesn't do a DNS lookup (confirmed via wireshark), which is exactly what I would expect.  If you think it's doing a lookup, there are a number of reasons why it may be doing a lookup (depending on how configurable your native bind client is) and if you install wireshark (or use a suitable network analyzer) you can quickly find out if you're looking up yourself.

Edit: note that the name lookup would be in the `.getLocalHost()` portion of the chained calls, if it was to be looked-up at all.

Comment: Why do you think it is relevant that it is a native method? Even if the method was implemented in Java, you cannot rely on a specific behaviour unless it is specified in the API documentation.

Comment: Native methods have no single specific implementation, instead there is an implementation per platform.  This means that to know the code will never do a DNS lookup would require knowing that nobody ever wrote (or will write) an implementation that eventually backs to something that does a DNS lookup.  That's just not possible, and the Java behavior is clear on what the call is to provide, but it is not clear on how it will be done.  Some person out there might implement it on a platform that tends to select a DNS solution before it is really necessary.

Comment: No method in the standard Java API has a single specific implementation. It is irrelevant if the method is native or if it is implemented in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`InetAddress` (in particular, the result of `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`) represents an IP address, and `getHostAddress()` returns its textual representation, therefore it doesn't need DNS lookup.

If you need a host name, you can call `getHostName()` - it may perform a reverse DNS lookup:

> If this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will be remembered and returned; otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured name lookup service. If a lookup of the name service is required, call getCanonicalHostName.

Answer (score 0):

InetAddress.getLocalHost() doesn't do what most people think that it does. It actually returns the hostname of the machine, and the IP address associated with that hostname. This may be the address used to connect to the outside world. It may not. It just depends on how you have your system configured.

On my windowsbox it gets the machine name and the external ip address. On my linux box it returns hostname and 127.0.0.1 because I have it set so in /etc/hosts

No use of DNS server involved here.